# How to find out the source of a part of a Wordpress page?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need to edit a typo on a Wordpress webpage, but I cannot find where that typo is in the source code. Here's what I have tried:

- on the Wordpress webpage, go directly to "Edit page" of the wp-admin, then Text. But I cannot see that part of the page. I think it belongs to the header, the Edit page function only shows the bottom half of the page.
- search for that exact typo in the database, namely the wp-posts, using phpMyadmin. I cannot find it.
- search for that exact typo in the in the files of theme folder that I have downloaded locally. I cannot find it either.

When I use the "Inspect Element" function of the browser, I can see the part of the typo. But for the life of me I cannot find where it is to correct it. Please help.

Comment: Did you search your codebase for the typo?  What "wordpress webpage" does it show up on?  Is it a page, a post, or other?

Comment: Have you tried disabling all of your plugins to see if one of them adds it?

Comment: By "code base", do you mean all files in the theme folder? It is a page, and when I edit that page in wp-admin, the html code only shows the bottom part, not the top part with the typo.

Comment: if it's in the header of the theme, this text with the typo may be customised in the admin in "Appearance" -> "Customise".